# Can't read Mocked Java.io.Reader

Tags: junit, mockito, java-io

I want to test following code with Mockito:

```
public static String funcToTest(String query) throws Exception {
    String url = Config.getURL(serviceName);
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
    String resultantString= "";

    method.setQueryString(URIUtil.encodeQuery(query));
    client.executeMethod(method);
    if (method.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(method
                    .getResponseBodyAsStream());
        int charValue = 0;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(1024);
        while ((charValue = reader.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) charValue);
        }
        resultantString = sb.toString();
    }
    method.releaseConnection();
    return resultantString;
}
```

I created the test like following:

```
@Test
public void testFunc() throws Exception{
    HttpMethod method =  Mockito.mock(HttpMethod.class);
    InputStream inputStream = Mockito.mock(InputStream.class);
    Reader reader = Mockito.mock(Reader.class);

    when(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Reader.class).withArguments(eq(inputStream)).thenReturn(reader);

    Mockito.when(reader.read()).thenReturn((int)'1', -1);


    String actualResult = cls.funcToTest("");
    String expected = "1";
    assertEquals(expected, actualResult);
}
```

But the `reader.read()` method is not returning 1. Instead it always returns -1. How should I mock `Reader` so that `read()` method will return something else other than -1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must work, I'm sorry what make you slightly confused )

```
// annotations is very important, cls I your tested class name, i assume cls is yours

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({cls.class})
public class PrinterTest {

    @Test
    public void print() throws Exception {

        String url = "";
        GetMethod method = Mockito.mock(GetMethod.class);
        InputStream inputStream = Mockito.mock(InputStream.class);
        InputStreamReader reader = Mockito.mock(InputStreamReader.class);

        Mockito.when(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);
        //forgot about it )
        PowerMockito.whenNew(GetMethod.class).withArguments(eq(url)).thenReturn(method);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(InputStreamReader.class).withArguments(eq(inputStream)).thenReturn(reader);


        Mockito.when(reader.read()).thenReturn((int) '1', -1);
        when(method.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);

        String actualResult = cls.funcToTest(url);
        String expected = "1";
        assertEquals(expected, actualResult);
    }


}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(inputStream.read());` prints 1, but `resultReader.read()` method inside while loop returns -1 every single time. So it `sb` is always empty.

Comment: Please update your post and give whole tested class, it's really vague now. But your output is -1 because you don't pass your mock object in real method, it's create other input stream. Try PowerMockito.whenNew(InputStreamReader.class).withArguments(eq(expectedArg1), eq(expectedArg2), ...).thenReturn(expectedReader); it will help you inject your mock

Comment: I already tried `PowerMockito.whenNew(InputStreamReader.class).withArguments(inputStream).thenReturn(reader);`, but here we do new on InputStreamReader class and get Reader object. So it gives an error for not matching arguments. NB. I updated the question.

Comment: you forgot eq() mather, try again eq(inputStream)

Comment: I eddited answer, don't forget Mockito.when(reader.read()).thenReturn('1', -1);

Comment: I'm having real trouble following this answer.  You don't seem to have said what the actual problem is.  There's no text explanation; just a link to some documentation which may or may not help the OP out.  Then you've given two different versions of the same method.  Which one is supposed to work?  And you close out your answer by insulting the OP.  What benefit are they supposed to get from this?

Comment: This conversation started yesterday and how you can read i knew only part of information about problem at first. I wasn't able to leave a comment about problem below question but i exactly knew kind of problem, and i wrote this at first part of answer. Later question was updated by my request, and i also update my answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my code quality. I am new in JUnit. so, it's taking a bit time. I updated my code as u said and updated in the question also. Still I am getting the same problem. My `reader.read()` method is giving me -1 always.

Comment: Add before method invocation when(method.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK); I'll try to write something like your code.

Comment: I debug the code and it goes till while loop and the value of `method.getStatusCode()` is `HttpStatus.SC_OK`. So, Looks like that's also fine. The only problem is, I think the mocked reader object is not going to the actual function.

Comment: @Emi I edited my answer.Try now, I think it will work. @PrepareForTest({cls.class})

Answer (score 1):

First of all , your test code is doing lots of `.class` mocking to mock function local variables / references. Mocking is for class dependencies and not for function local variables.

As written, you can't test your function `funcToTest` with mocking alone. You need to rewrite this function if not willing to use real objects for - `HttpMethod` & `Reader`.

You need to remove object creation code with `new` outside this function if you wish to mock calls on those objects and replace code of `new` with this get method. e.g.

```
protected HttpMethod getHttpMethod(String Url){
   return new GetMethod(url);
}
```

Also, I don't see you mocking this line for a fake URL - it seems necessary for unit testing.

```
String url = Config.getURL(serviceName);
```

After taking object creation code outside your function, you need to create a new class than extends your `SUT` ( Subject Under Test ) and you override these methods (  `getHttpMethod`) to provide fake/mocked instances.

You need to write similar method to get `Reader` instance.

Then you test this new class - extended from your SUT since object creation logic need not to be tested.

Without taking object creation code outside the function, I don't see a way of mocking it by mockito.

Hope it helps !!